# FilterDefinition CamlQuery

Tags: caml-query, alert, user

I working with custom AlertTemplate. I only want to send an Alert if field "Beställare" or "Agent" contains my UserId I Have tried with this query, but I always get an Alert when something chanches.

```
    <Query>
  <And>
   <Or>
    <Eq>
        <Value type="integer"><UserID /></Value>
        <FieldRef name="Best%5Fx00e4%5Fllare/New"/>
    </Eq>
    <Eq>
        <Value type="integer"><UserID /></Value>
        <FieldRef name="Agent/New"/>
    </Eq>
   </Or>
  </And>
 </Query>
```

How will I change by query so I only get alerts for the conditions above?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `<UserID>` element like you've done is absolutely right. Compare your CAML to the [official MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625789.aspx) here -- perhaps try placing your `<Value>` node below the `<FieldRef>` nodes as they have done. Everything else looks okay.

Alternatively, any time you create a new alert template you will need to do these **three** things before your changes will take effect:

- Load your your custom alert template XML into SharePoint with the [updatealerttemplates STSADM command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd278299%28office.12%29.aspx)
- Associate you new alert template with your list as follows:

  ```
  SPAlertTemplateCollection alertTemplates = new SPAlertTemplateCollection((SPWebService)(SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.Parent)); 
  list.AlertTemplate = alertTemplates["Your Template Name"];
  list.Update();
  ```
- Restart IIS (sometimes you may need to restart "SharePoint 2010 Timer" service too)

Comment: I get the same result when I try to change order and restart the iis ans the service. The other things I have done before.

Comment: If you've followed all the steps above, then the only room for error are the `<FieldRef>` attributes in your CAML. Try this...  1) query only the "Agent" field (the special characters in your other field name may be causing errors). 2) Remove "/New" from the field name, and 3) add `LookupId="True"` to the `<FieldRef>` tag. See the [official FieldRef Element definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms442728.aspx) (make sure you read then comments at the bottom re: the LookupId property)